# A function in $H^\infty(\Delta^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables, hardy-spaces

Can you give an example of a function $f\in H^\infty(\Delta^2)$ with $f^{-1}\in L^\infty(T^2)$ but not inner? Here $H^\infty(\Delta^2)$ is the space of all bounded analytic functions defined on bi-disc $\Delta^2$ and $T^2$ is torus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. I assume that $f^{-1} = 1/f$? (The standard interpretation as the inverse of $f$ doesn't make sense.) Also, I assume that by *inner* you mean that the boundary value has modulus (suitably interpreted) has modulus $1$ almost everywhere.

If that is the case, almost any bounded zero-free holomorphic function will do. Take for example $f(z,w) = z-2$.